# React API communication refuse on cloud IDE (MERN Stack)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm learning MERN stack following the below tutorial.
https://medium.com/@beaucarnes/learn-the-mern-stack-by-building-an-exercise-tracker-mern-tutorial-59c13c1237a1

I've decided to use a cloud platform IDE called goorm IDE (https://ide.goorm.io) which is similar to cloud 9 IDE, and as I followed the tutorial, I realized a simple problem, that the testing environment is little different because I can not access the localhost on my machine (Or at least I don't know how to.)

Working on the back End did not have much problem because this IDE provides a domain where I can access and I could just run the server.js (not the whole react app) and test the API end point easily.
But now that I run the whole react app as I'm learning Front End side, I discovered that my server.js is not accessible as before when I was running just the server and I would get refused from the connection as below.

Below code is the actual code I'm using from the front End side in order to make API call to the server.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/add', user).then(res => console.log(res.data));
// I tried changing the url to external domain.. changing the directory.. with no luck..
```

And below is the code for server.js file.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }
);

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("Mongo DB database connection established successfully");
});

const exercisesRouter = require('./routes/exercises');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/exercises', exercisesRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.listen(port, process.env.IP, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

And below is the url of the page where I'm actually trying to make the API Call.
https://zimen.run.goorm.io/user

Other environment information

- Running URL and Port setting from the IDE : https://zimen.run.goorm.io:3000
- React App directory : root/mern-exercise-tracker/
- dependencies : express, create-react-app, mongoose, cors

I'm wondering if it would be better to start the whole project again in a clean local environment..
If someone could please help, it would be much appreciated.

Any other information needed, please let me know, or you can actually join the IDE online as this is a cloud IDE.

Thank you in advance.

== UPDATE ==

Sorry I've forgotten to attach the error log.

```
xhr.js:178 POST https://localhost:3000/users/add net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
```

Comment: What error are you getting when trying to make an api call

Comment: Hi Shubham, Thanks for the comment. I've updated the question with the error log.

Answer (score 0):

its seems you have `CORS` error,i solved this problem by installing `CORS` extension on `Goolge Chrome`

Answer (score 0):

Set `PORT=5000` in Nodejs server-side and the default port for React frontend as `PORT=3000`.

Set your own separate custom 'Running URL and Port' for Nodejs and React.

Example:

> https://[custom-client-side-name].goorm.io

for React at `PORT=3000`
and

> https://[custom-server-side-name].goorm.io

for Nodejs at `PORT=5000`

For Axios command on React side, use:

```
axios.post('https://my-server-side.goorm.io/users/add', user).then(res => console.log(res.data));
```

and similarly, the React frontend can be found on your custom website you have set up: [https://my-client-side.goorm.io/[custom-routes]](https://my-client-side.goorm.io/%5Bcustom-routes%5D)